# Create Excel workbook without any sheet

Tags: c#, excel

Is there a way to create an `Excel` workbook without any sheets in it?

This is the code that I use to create the workbook:

```
excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
```

I tried also adding

```
excelApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 0;
```

before the creation of the `excelBook` but the minimum value is 1 so the program crashes.

EDIT:

Tried also to delete the first sheet as soon as it is created but still doesn't work

```
Sheets excelSheetsToDelete = excelBook.Sheets[1];
excelSheetsToDelete.Delete();
```

I would like to be able to add my sheets with my names later without having to rename the first one.

Comment: Having one sheet is the default behavior of excel. Even when you open a new file in excel it is opened with one sheet and it can't be deleted. So that's what you need to live with. You can delete the default created sheet when you add your own new sheet.

Comment: I've edited my answer with the code I tried to delete the first sheet but it crashes.

Comment: Without a sheet its not as if you can do anything to the file anyways, why not reserve creation of the excel till you need to name at least 1 sheet and then create it.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You can change the workbook's `.xlsx` extension to `.zip` and then mess around with the contents. I tried removing all the sheets, but i got an error when i opened the workbook again. Maybe there is something you can do with this technique which won't cause an error?!

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an Excel without any sheet, Excel must contain at least one sheet. Try to delete single sheet in Excel application (desktop). You won't do that.

Comment: This certainly appears to be true but is there any documentation that states this?

Comment: I know from experience this is true but would also like to see any official documentation.

Comment: Tried and failed to find any official documentation where this is described.

Answer (score 0):

Like people have already said, Excel must contain at least 1 visible worksheet at all times. Since it seems like you just want to create a workbook, and manually specify your sheet name without having to rename the one created automatically, I wrote this quick VB Script that may work for you.

```
Dim objShell, objExcel, objWorksheet, strSheetName
strSheetName = InputBox("Enter a name for your new Worksheet:")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("EXCEL.EXE")
WScript.Sleep 3000 'Wait for new excel file to open
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set objWorksheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Name = strSheetName
```

What this does is prompt you to enter a name for your new sheet. It then runs a new instance of Excel and sets the first worksheet of the newly created file as the name you specified.

If Excel includes 3 sheets when creating new workbooks, you can change this to 1 by going in any excel worbook and clicking - File > Options > General - and look for the "When the creating new workbooks" separator. There will be an option "Include this many sheets" which you can change to 1.

Also, to confirm what people have already said, if you try and change this value to 0, it will tell you "The entry must be greater than or equal to 1" meaning all workbooks must contain at least 1 visible worksheet. Hope this helped.